# XPATH - grab text after strong tag

Tags: xpath

```
<div class="school_row_cell_content">
<div class="center_div">
    <img src="/assets/isbiimages/c1504.jpg" alt="School Crest" width="190"></div>
                 Shelburne Road,
<br class="">Cheltenham,
<br class="">Gloucestershire,
<br class="">United Kingdom,
<br class="">GL51 6HE
<br class="">
<br class=""><strong>Tel:</strong> +44 1242 258000
<br class=""><strong>Fax:</strong> +44 1242 258004
<br class=""><br class=""><strong><a href="http://www.deanclose.org.uk" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" id="154" title="opens in new window" class="school_website_btn">Visit School Website</a></strong>
<br class="">
<br class=""><strong>Founded:</strong>1886<br class=""><br class=""><strong>Headmaster:</strong>
<br class=""><a href="/assets/isbiimages/ph1504.jpg" class="iframe_popups">Mr Bradley Salisbury</a>
<br class=""><br class=""><strong>Registrar:</strong>
<br class="">Mrs Kelly Serjeant
<br class="">
<br class="">This school offers flexi-boarding.
<br class="">
<br class=""><strong>Accreditations and affiliations:</strong>
<br class="">ISBA, HMC, BSA, AGBIS
<br class=""><strong>Religious affiliation:</strong>
<br class="">Church of England<br class=""><strong>Teaching languages:</strong>
<br class="">English
<br class="">                                           
</div>
```

I am trying to grab certain fields based on their label, for example, I want to grab "Founded;" which would be 1886 in this example. And also "Registrar:" which would be Mrs Kelly Serjeant.

I am trying variations of this with no luck:

```
//strong[starts-with(., 'Registrar:')]//text()[not(parent::strong)]
```

Not quite sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
//div[@class="school_row_cell_content"]//text()[.="Registrar:"]/following::text()[string-length()>0][1]
```

to get `Mrs Kelly Serjeant`.

Replace `"Registrar:"` to `"Founded:"` as

```
//div[@class="school_row_cell_content"]//text()[.="Founded:"]/following::text()[string-length()>0][1]
```

to get `1886`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below xPath by just replacing the text in contains section

`//*[contains(text(),'Founded')]/following-sibling::text()[string-length()>1][position()<2]`